# Shiny Server Reactive Function Issues: The condition has a length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, shiny, probability

Strangely enough, I've gotten a reactive issue in conjunction with an error that tells me that "non-numeric argument to binary operator". But here's what I've done with the server code. It's prohibiting my final output$PredictionX from rendering. Thanks.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  sliderValues1 <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("aoff", #TeamAoffrtg
               "adef", #TeamAdefrtg
               "boff", #TeamBoffrtg
               "bdef", #TeamBdefrtg
               "homecourt"),#Homecourt
      Value = as.double(c(input$aoff, 
                          input$adef,
                          input$boff,
                          input$bdef,
                          input$homecourt)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  }) 
  sliderValues2 <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("aoff2", #TeamAoffrtg
               "adef2", #TeamAdefrtg
               "boff2", #TeamBoffrtg
               "bdef2", #TeamBdefrtg
               "ot2", #Overtime
               "combpace2"),#CombinedPace
      Value = as.double(c(input$aoff2, 
                          input$adef2,
                          input$boff2,
                          input$bdef2,
                          input$ot2,
                          input$combpace2)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  }) 

  function1 <- function(aoff,adef,boff,bdef,homecourt) {
    100*((exp(-1.9418+.1572*aoff-.144*adef-.139*boff+.1414*bdef+.4341*homecourt))/(1+exp(-1.9418+.1572*aoff-.144*adef-.139*boff+.1414*bdef+.4341*homecourt)))
  }
  function2 <- function(aoff2,adef,boff,bdef,ot2,combpace2) {
    100*((exp(-74.6058-.0788*aoff2+.0874*adef+.0795*boff-.09166*bdef+2.8053*ot2+.1897*combpace2))/(1+exp(-74.6058-.0788*aoff2+.0874*adef+.0795*boff-.09166*bdef+2.8053*ot2+.1897*combpace2)))
  }

  predtype <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Name3 = "TeamAWin",
      Value3 = input$Occur,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

  })

  output$Prediction1 <- renderText({
    # predtype <- input$Occur

    if (predtype() == "TeamAWin"){
    c(round(function1((input$aoff),(input$adef),(input$boff),(input$bdef),(input$homecourt)),4),"%")
    # return(pred)
    }
    else {}
    })
  output$Prediction2 <- renderText({
    # predtype <- input$Occur
    if (predtype() == "BothTeamsAllow110+"){
    c(round(function2(input$aoff2, input$adef2,input$boff2,input$bdef2,input$ot2,input$combpace2),4),"%")
    # return(pred)
    }
    else {}
  })

}
)
```

Comment: you might want to use `paste` instead of `c` in the `renderText`

Comment: also `if (predtype()$Name3 == "TeamAWin"){`